# Changing link_to path based on helper variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a helper method that I want to use for several models to save having to repeat the same code several times.

```
def link_to_follow(instance:instance,type:type)
  link_to('Unfollow', unfollow_books_path(id: instance.id), 
          method: :post, 
          id: "unfollow_link_#{instance.id}",
          remote: true)
end
```

How do I do it so that if I pass `type:'magazine'` as a variable then `unfollow_books_path` becomes `unfollow_magazines_path` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
def link_to_follow(instance:instance, type:type)
  link_to(
    'Unfollow', 
    send("unfollow_#{type.pluralize}_path", instance), 
    method: :post, 
    id: "unfollow_link_#{instance.id}",
    remote: true
  )
end
```

I suppose you might also be able to do:

```
def link_to_follow(instance:instance)
  link_to(
    'Unfollow', 
    send("unfollow_#{instance.class.name.underscore.pluralize}_path", instance), 
    method: :post, 
    id: "unfollow_link_#{instance.id}",
    remote: true
  )
end
```

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thanks!